# What controls the list of supported languages of an iPhone app in iTunes?

Tags: ios, localization

What controls the languages shown as supported in an iPhone app's iTunes page (in the right side, below "Description", under "Languages")? From the iTunes Connect Developer's Guide it appears it's not something you choose during submission. I assume it's something in the bundle.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering too why my English-only app apparently supports French, German, Spanish, and Northern Sami.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I used a technical support incident to ask this question of Apple directly. Here is the answer:

"The list of languages supported by the app, as shown in the iTunes store screenshot
you sent, is automatically determined by inspecting the submitted application bundle.
Typically, this comes from the .lproj folders in a bundle, as the process (and iOS)
use this to determine what languages the application can support.  However, it is
also possible to provide your own localization support system in the application
without using .lproj folders (although this is typically much more work) -- in
this scenario, the list of supported languages is specified in the application's plist
file, via the CFBundleLocalizations key.  See the following docs (and the guide linked
to in the docs) for more info on this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-109552-TPXREF111
"

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to specify anything in iTunes Connect. They seem to scan the contents of the bundle and look at the localization subdirectories: I’ve got en.lproj, nl.lproj, and de.lproj in my app and iTunes lists "English, Dutch and German" as supported languages.

Comment: What if you don't do localization like that, can you just add empty directories? Do you know if there's any official spec that says this is how it works and there's no other way?

Comment: @crackers: Sorry, I don’t know about that. I’m not sure if it is a good idea to do localization in a different way, since iPhone OS wouldn’t let the user select his preferred language for the app then.

Comment: The problem is that the cost to experiment is high, with the whole store submission process. Maybe I could get more info by asking Apple directly (yeah, right). BTW, the app handles its own settings, so it's not a problem in this regard. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I know this was posted a long time ago, but I had to comment this. A good reason to do the localization in a different way is to write portable code (which makes it easier to port your app to Android and/or PC).