# Hide extra localizations on itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, itunes

I tried to google this but could not find any suitable answer, I'm about to publish an App that has some third party lib integrated, and this lib has multiple localizations while my app is in English only.

My problem is, when my app is published on iTunes, I'm afraid iTunes may show the app as having multiple localizations, and that would be a lie, since only the lib has translations.

For this release, I will simply remove the extra localizations from the lib to prevent any user confusion on downloading the app, but I would like to know if it is possible to leave the translations for the lib in the project while being sure itunes wont show the app as having multiple localizations.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why don't you just remove contents from  InfoPlist.strings used by lib ?

Comment: But that is not the question. I want to know if it is possible To Leave those translations only on the lib, but still make sure itunes won't show the whole app as translated, since it won't be.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this?

> "*Try to look at the info.plist which defines localizations and I guess some work in iTunesConnect should be done as well, but before approving an app.*"
>
> "*Info.plist has a key CFBundleLocalizations which Xcode displays as Localizations is an array where you list the country codes. I did not do anything in iTunes Connect, but now it correctly reads the binary details after upload.*"

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/6747725/1344459
I hope that helps you.

Comment: Ah, no, hadn't found that one yet. I'll give it a shot and check back in here to report on how it goes.

Comment: That was a promising lead, but it didn't work. I set the `CFBundleLocalizations` to `en` and uploaded, but iTunes still reports that German is supported. I also tried the string `English` before I realized it was supposed to be an ISO code. No change in either case. Also, I can't seem to find anything to tweak in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @JoshEarl When you create a new app in iTunesConnect, one of the fields you need to select is the default language. You can see an example: [Displaying on the Store in More Than One Language (Optional)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html) I'm not sure if that what you are looking for.

Comment: From what I can see, the language settings in iTunes Connect allow you to translate your app's metadata (description, etc.) into multiple languages. The issue I'm dealing with is the app itself. In the iTunes listing, under the Information header, there's a section for Languages. The languages appear to be extracted from the binary, and I'm trying to figure out how to tell iTunes what languages the app actually supports. Apple seems to ignore the `CFBundleLocalizations` property and assumes that they can correctly infer what languages are supported by scanning the binary.

Comment: @JoshEarl I see... Can you remove the localization subdirectory: de.lproj (German) from your app? via http://stackoverflow.com/a/4146668/1344459

Comment: I did try removing all of the localization subdirectories that I have access to, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Dear god, this question came alive! @JoshEarl I'll be monitoring this thread, if any solution works, I will accept it.

Comment: A bounty will do that. :) I haven't found a solution yet, despite all the replies. If I do, I'll post a comment or answer here.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, iTunes shows German as a supported language. I found a de.lproj folder in one of the third party libraries I'm using and deleted it to *hopefully* fix the problem. Obviously, I can't test until my next App Store submission :\

Answer (score 3):

Check the following image. I think if you declare only English here then you are good to go. As for the 3rd party libraries that are using localization, you might need to handle that in your app in case user has set a different language than english (but you can test it if that will occur). Other than that, I think by setting languages as in below picture, you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had several languages showing up in here from the third party libraries. None of them were showing up in iTunes except for German, oddly. I deleted the `lproj` folders, but iTunes still thinks the binary supports German.

Comment: Try cleaning the project and then building it, may be it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid additional localizations by explicitly setting your App's `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22296030/1049134).

Comment: Thanks, but this describes a pretty different scenario than what I'm dealing with. And in our case, we will soon be supporting multiple languages, rather than removing them.